# Same TCP Socket (client-side) with two different scanners and two different BufferedReader

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcpsocket

how can I download strings with two different objects BufferedReader and two different objects Scanner from a single socket with two different threads?
I already tried this solution below but myReader1, after reading from Socket, is with invalid characters how can I fix? You might suggest a workaround? Thanks a lot in advance

```
    //Socket TCP declaration
   InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(IP);

   try
   {
       Socket mySocket  = new Socket(serverAddr, PORT);
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }


    //Thread 1
   Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable()
   {
     @Override
     public void run() 
     {
        BufferedReader myReader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mySocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        Scanner myScanner1 = new Scanner(myReader1).useDelimiter("\0");

       synchronized(mySocket)
       {
         while(mySocket.isConnected() && myScanner1.hasNext())
         {
            String s = myScanner1.next();
         }
       }
    }
 });

  Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable()
  {
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
      BufferedReader myReader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mySocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

      Scanner myScanner2 = new Scanner(myReader2).useDelimiter("\0");

      synchronized(mySocket)
      {
         while(mySocket.isConnected() && myScanner2.hasNext())
         {
            String s = myScanner2.next();
         }
      }
  }
});

 t1.start();
 t2.start();
```

Comment: Hi, what is the _Android_ relationship here?

Comment: If you want to multi-thread your I/O you will need to use something like ServerSocket and call accept() which returns a new Socket. A Socket should only be managed by one thread but one thread can manage many Sockets. The idea being that for each new connection, a new socket is created but that socket is only managed by a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I download strings with two different objects BufferedReader and two different objects Scanner from a single socket with two different threads?

You can't .

You will never get this to work. Because of aspects of TCP you can't control, the data will arrive in unpredictable quanta, and the `BufferedReaders` will steal it from each other in unpredictable ways. Ditto the `Scanners` themselves if they have internal buffering.

In any case what you are trying to do has no actual meaning. What are you expecting the two threads to do that a single thread won't? If for example you're expecting them to read alternately, they won't. If you're expecting to be able to confidently send one string intended for thread 1 and another string intended for thread 2, you can't. It is impossible.

> I already tried this solution below but myReader1, after reading from Socket, is with invalid characters how can I fix? You might suggest a workaround?

You won't succeed in getting anything working at all along the lines you've started on, but the basis of any solution must be a single `Scanner` and a single `BufferedReader` per socket. If you must have two threads you will need two sockets, with a `BufferedReader` and `Scanner` each.

```
try
{
    Socket mySocket  = new Socket(serverAddr, PORT);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Don't write code like this. First, you should only be catching `IOException.` Second, all the code that depends on the success of this code should be logically inside this try block. It should be impossible for any code anywhere to access the `mySocket` variable unless this code has succeeded.

```
while(mySocket.isConnected() && myScanner1.hasNext())
```

The `isConnected()` test is pointless here. It will never return false. It doesn't magically become false when the peer disconnects.